# Wether to make a service stateless or stateful in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: microservices, azure-service-fabric, stateless, stateful

I have microservice which basically read and update data on an Azure Storage table
Read and Update function are implemented as REST calls.I am confused whether to make it stateless or stateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a service needs to keep its own state, make it Stateful. If your service uses an external store for state, it's probably fine to make a Stateless service.

So unless you need run a workflow that calls several REST services and need to support retries, progress tracking, store intermediate results, etc. it's probably ok to go with a Stateless service.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain state (reliable collection) in a service, then you need to use a stateful service.